# uninstalled cracklib-dicts, sudo gone, how to recover

Tags: yum, sudo, amazon-linux

I was trying to install the packer utility to build AWS AMI's. However it was conflicting with a builtin utility of the same name, which is part of the cracklib-dicts package.

I used yum to remove cracklib-dicts, however for some reason this also removed a bunch of other utilities, including sudo!

Is there any way to recover from this? I've never had a root password for this system.

I don't even know where to start to fix this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35929/13796

Comment: It prints the package list and asks "Are you sure?" for exactly this reason. You're supposed to inspect the list carefully before approving the operation. At this point the fastest thing to do is probably to start a new instance.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more careful. I kind of assumed that it wouldn't remove such a critically important package. All fine now. I was able to restore the server from a recent snapshot.